# Can I cap the amount of RAM WSL can use to 512 Megabytes of RAM?

Tags: memory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I’m trying to cap the amount of ram WSL uses. I have this config set:

```
[wsl2]
Memory = 4GB
Processors = 1
```

I know GB is gigabyte, but im trying to limit the amount of memory to 512 megabytes, would it be MB? Or M?

I tried both MB and M, but none of them worked. How do I limit to only 512MB?I only have 3GB of RAM on my computer. I also tried to put 0.5GB in the `Memory` value, still didn't work.

Comment: According to [the official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) it seems like it is all GB; but knowing that what about going fractional and setting it as: `0.5GB`

Comment: My bad, I should have included this in the question: ive tried 0.5GB

Comment: Good to know. But please, nobody other than me and you have seen your edits. So no need to add “Extra Information” and such. Just edit your question to add the new information in context. All should be good.

Comment: See my answer below - "512MB" is supposedly correct.  When you say "didn't work", can you elaborate on what you are seeing?

Comment: It doesn't seem like 512MB works, wsl still takes upto 1GB of ram, even when setting it to 512MB

Answer (score 1):

### `512MB` should work.

From the [Release Notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18945):

> `<size> entries must be size followed by unit, for example 8GB or 512MB`

Full Documentation:

> ```
> [wsl2]
> kernel=<path>              # An absolute Windows path to a custom Linux kernel.
> memory=<size>              # How much memory to assign to the WSL2 VM.
> processors=<number>        # How many processors to assign to the WSL2 VM.
> swap=<size>                # How much swap space to add to the WSL2 VM. 0 for no swap file.
> swapFile=<path>            # An absolute Windows path to the swap vhd.
> localhostForwarding=<bool> # Boolean specifying if ports bound to wildcard or >localhost in the WSL2 VM should be connectable from the host via localhost:port (default true).
>
> # <path> entries must be absolute Windows paths with escaped backslashes, for example C:\\Users\\Ben\\kernel
> # <size> entries must be size followed by unit, for example 8GB or 512MB.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes for this feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18945) say that 512MB is the correct form. Also, [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166#issuecomment-663487284) on a related Github issue mentions changing it to 512MB and it working, although the thread is locked, so there's no way to confirm that with a reply in that issue.